# Generate random numbers following the exponential distribution in a given interval $[a, b]$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I  know that to genarete ramdom variables following exponential distribution just do: 
$$X=-\frac{1}{\lambda}ln(U)$$

where $U\sim U(0,1)$

Now, to find a distribution restricted to the interval $(a, b)$, I used the truncated distribution ([Trucated distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution)) coming in the following cumulative distribution 
$$H(t)=\frac{e^{-\lambda a}-e^{-\lambda t}}{e^{-\lambda b}-e^{-\lambda a}}$$

However I don't Know to find the inverse function $H^{-1}$. Also I don't know if this expression is correct.
I thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the random variable
$$
X=x-\frac1\lambda\cdot\log(U+u),
$$
for some suitable $(u,x)$. Unless I am mistaken, if $(u,x)$ solves
$$
\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}=\mathrm e^{-\lambda a}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda b},\quad u=\mathrm e^{-\lambda(b-x)},
$$
then $X$ is uniform on $(a,b)$.

**Edit:** Note that if
$$
H(t)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda a}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}}{\mathrm e^{-\lambda b}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda a}},
$$
then
$$
t=-\frac1{\lambda}\cdot\log\left(H(t)\mathrm e^{-\lambda b}+(1-H(t))\mathrm e^{-\lambda a}\right).
$$
In terms of $(u,x)$ introduced above, this reads
$$
t=x-\frac1{\lambda}\cdot\log\left(1-H(t)+u\right).
$$
Note finally that, if $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ then $X$ and $X'$ are identically distributed, where $X$ is defined above and
$$
X'=x-\frac1\lambda\cdot\log(1-U+u),
$$

Comment: How you found this expression ? it was from my function H

Comment: You want to shift and/or dilate the usual answer to pass from (0,+oo) to (a,b), playing with two parameters (x,u) seems like a move which might work. Once the idea is there, one writes down the equations--and it works.

Comment: The main problem is to find this inverse, I can not isolate the x in this expression

Comment: Sorry but I am not following. Which expression? Yours? Then show it otherwise we are just whistling in the wind. Or mine? Then x is quite explicit.

Comment: Sorry I did not express myself right, to find the distribution achieving just find the inverse function H described above. I just can not flip and get the expression you mentioned

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $